# Pass scope to a factory for use in Jquery animation

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to run a bit of jQuery code on a form submit. I want it to be reusable, and I already have a factory set up for swapping data between Controllers.

**HTML** ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GFV9H/))

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div id="div_1" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <form ng-submit="Data.submit('#div_1','#div_2')">
            <input type="text" ng-model="Data.FirstName"><br>
            Input is : <strong>{{Data.FirstName}}</strong>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="div_2" style="display:none;" ng-controller="SecondCtrl">
        Second controller to verify data is being shared: <br>
        <strong>{{Data.FirstName}}</strong>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.factory('Data', function(){
    var root = {
        FirstName: ''
    };
    root.submit = function(to_hide, to_show) {
        $(to_hide).slideUp(function(){
            $(to_show).slideDown();
        });
    }
    return root;
});
myApp.controller('FirstCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){
    $scope.Data = Data;
});
myApp.controller('SecondCtrl', function( $scope, Data ){
    $scope.Data = Data;
});
```

This works, but I feel like I'm hacking it. Is there a better way of doing this?

**More importantly, what's the *Angular Way* of doing this?**

Btw, I'm not using ngAnimate because of pure CSS animations. I still want older browsers to experience the anims.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DOM manipulation call should probably be encapsulated in a directive. Pass the elements to manipulate and the `Data` object to the directive.

Directive:

```
myApp.directive('hideShow', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            hideSelector: '=',
            showSelector: '=',
            data: '=hideShow'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert(scope.data.FirstName);
                $(scope.hideSelector).slideUp(function(){
                    $(scope.showSelector).slideDown();
                });
            });
        }
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="div_1" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
    <form hide-show="Data" hide-selector="'#div_1'" show-selector="'#div_2'">
        <input type="text" ng-model="Data.FirstName"><br>
        Input is : <strong>{{Data.FirstName}}</strong>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
</div>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GFV9H/1/